# 'C:Program' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, .net, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

Trying to send the code below to the command line, but I get errors. I know there is an issue with backslashes sent to CMD. Any help here on how to send it? Thanks!

```
string strCmdText="/C C:\\Program Files\\MetaTrader 5\\terminal64.exe /config:C:\\Users\\vguer036\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\D0E8209F77C8CF37AD8BF550E51FF075\\config\\common.ini";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Comment: try putting an @ in front of the string?

Comment: You probably want `string strCmdText=@"/C ""C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\terminal64.exe"" ""/config:C:\Users\vguer036\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\D0E8209F77C8CF37AD8BF550E51FF075\config\common.ini""";
`.

Comment: Why go through CMD to execute an application, Can't you "start" that "terminal64.exe" directly, with the rest as arguments?

Comment: Just use StartInfo with ShelExecute to true and assign the Arguments and FileName...

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Can you elaborate please? I'm very new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use this:

```
string strCmdText="/C C:\\Program Files\\MetaTrader 5\\terminal64.exe /config:C:\\Users\\vguer036\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\D0E8209F77C8CF37AD8BF550E51FF075\\config\\common.ini";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

then you are trying to start the application CMD.exe, which in turn you instruct to execute a particular application. However, because of the spaces, what CMD is trying to execute is the command `C:\\Program` with parameters `Files\\MetaTrader`, `5\\terminal64.exe` etc. That is where your error message comes from.

One way to solve this is to add extra quotes around the filename (as Dour High Arch commented):

```
string strCmdText=@"/C ""C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\terminal64.exe"" ""/config:C:\Users\vguer036\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\D0E8209F77C8CF37AD8BF550E51FF075\config\common.ini""";
```

Note the doubled quotes, which are required to use a literal quote inside a verbatim string literal (`@"..."`).

But this way you are still executing one application (CMD.exe) to start another (terminal64.exe). Why not start that terminal64 directly?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
     @"C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\terminal64.exe",
     @"/config:C:\Users\vguer036\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\D0E8209F77C8CF37AD8BF550E51FF075\config\common.ini");
```

You should experiment to see whether you need extra quotes around that application name, but I don't think so.

Comment: The second solution worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!