# C# call command get 'C/:Program' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, windows

```cs
command = @"/C  ""C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin/mongodump.exe""   D:/hkorders  --uri=""mongodb://XXX:XXX@localhost:30000/XXX?authSource=admin""  -d hkorders";
var cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe",command);
cmdsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdsi.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmdsi.UseShellExecute = false;
           
var cmd = new Process() { StartInfo = cmdsi };
cmd.Start();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

i tried [method1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934402/cprogram-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command),but still not works, i know it cause by the space between program and files ,but i did not know how to resolve it

Comment: Make sure you are running exactly what you have built. Temporarily replace text "Program" with "ProgramX" and make sure you see this X in the error message.

Comment: Why do you need to go via `cmd` in the first place? Just execute `mongodump` directly

Comment: Only the (1st) .exe gets passed as "FileName". Everything else needs to go into "Arguments". In this case, `FileName = cmd.exe`. But as already mentioned, very seldom is it necessary to use `cmd.exe` with Process.

Answer (score 0):

i use `Progra~1` replace `Program File` , it works ok

Comment: This may work on your computer, but it may not work on another, because [short file names could be disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names).

Comment: @Dialecticus it's ok ,because my server environment is same as my dev env, it will only run on these host